# Reporting Services - Determine whether or not Stored Procedure returns garbage fields

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, sybase, ssrs-2008

I have to develop a report against Sybase and I am calling a stored procedure for the dataset using an exec statement in a text query.

This stored procedure, instead of returning no records when there are none available, returns a table with a different column structure than that which is returned when records are available.

This causes all of my fields to display #ERROR.  Is there a way to determine that the data set is going to return this garbage row so that I can hide the rows that are effected and handle the error?

Thanks so much for your help.

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is to check the IsMissing property on the dataset field:

Set the row's "Hidden" property to -

=IIF(Fields!FieldThatShouldBeThere.IsMissing,true,false)

Frank